# How scalable are virtual attributes in OData SAP Hybris?

Tags: odata, sap-commerce-cloud

I have some virtual attributes in SAP Hybris Integration Object.

Are these attributes scalable with much data?

How safe is it to have around 6 to 7 virtual attributes in a very big table?